# Not able to set validDomains inside the manifest of app in Microsoft registered app

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I want to use deeplinks to open a task module,
acc to the documentation, i formed the deep link url  as

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/b7636409-8e1a-40c0-b80a-7ea4bafdfcce?height=1000&width=1000&title=Preview&url=https://user-docviewer-testing.sentieo.com/?docid=61499c54f8fe3611c2738325&redirect=docviewer&src=app

the documenation further states that this url mentioned inside deeplinkurl should be under validDomains of the app manifest,
when i tried editing that, got an error in case of both list type validDomains and string type validDomains ...

What would be the right approach to  proceed with this?

[image: in case of string type validDomains -]
[image]

```
{
"id": "b7636409-8e1a-40c0-b80a-7ea4bafdfcce",
"validDomains": [ " * ", " *. youtube.com" ],
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "698ac0a6-9b05-47bf-a1be-d9fcfbcd3538",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-08-03T13:00:24Z",
"certification": null,
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "My Bot 2",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "sentieousa.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [],
"requiredResourceAccess": [],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do not add domains that are outside your control, either directly or through wildcards. For example, yourapp.onmicrosoft.com is valid, however, *.onmicrosoft.com is not valid.

Please have a look at this doc: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains

Comment: Hey Sayali, i tried adding "www.youtube.com"  in the validDomains list, and still got this error, Could you please confirm this from your end?

Comment: could  you please share manifest file?

Comment: could you please add the validdomain as given below.
"validDomains": [
" * ",
" *. youtube.com"
]

Comment: got the same error ...

Comment: have added manifest file in the question ...

Comment: @NehaSingla - Could you please share the manifest file so that we can check it from our end. Also could you please re-check the documentation for supported format for deeplink and validDomains.

Comment: @NehaSingla - As per documentation, it looks like deeplink does not support to open a Task Module.
Could you please check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/invoking-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax   and   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5mzneHw1M4. I have aleady added the manifest file in the question.

Comment: @NehaSingla -  Could you please share the app manifest file, we will check it from our end once.

Comment: Please find the manifest json in the question itself.

Comment: @NehaSingla - this is not valid manifest to creating a team apps. could you please refer the document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains 
also you can create a manifest using app studio in team.